# why the method for generating token via /oauth/token has been changed from GET to POST?

Tags: java, spring, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token

I was using **spring-security-oauth2-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar** and was able to access /oauth/token via **GET** method to generate tokens.
When I updated to **spring-security-oauth2-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar**, GET method was not supported. I am now only able to access /oauth/token to generate tokens via **POST** method.

Also "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler" was found missing in the new jar. Can anyone explain the reason?
Plz Help!
Thanx in advance

Comment: Hi I am using spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7. org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalH‌​andler is missing. How did you solve the issue?

Comment: Vinod: Use `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler` instead. Please provide values to properties: `tokenStore` & `requestFactory` [some impl of `OAuth2RequestFactory`]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the OAuth 2.0 specification mandates that requests to the token endpoint must use the `POST` method. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2 which says:

> The client MUST use the HTTP "POST" method when making access token
> requests.

Comment: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalH‌​‌​andler is missing. How did you solve the issue?

Comment: @VinodPatel I'm looking for TokenServicesUserApprovalH‌​‌​‌​andler too. How did you solve your issue ?

Comment: check answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158126/upgrading-spring-security-oauth2-1-0-5-release-to-2-0-5-release-getting-404

Comment: Use org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenS‌​toreUserApprovalHand‌​ler instead. Please provide values to properties: tokenStore & requestFactory [some impl of OAuth2RequestFactory]

Comment: Is there any way to replace 'post' with 'get'?